# "Update Cart" not triggering my woocommerce_after_cart_totals action hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a *woocommerce_after_cart_totals* hook action being done to output a specific JSON object to the cart page. It works as expected on page load, however when someone changes qty and hits Update Cart button,  the JSON variable disappears and a new one is not recreated.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_totals','custom_json_var_output',10,2);
function custom_json_var_output(){
    //build the variable to $output
    //............
    echo "<script>jsonCartData=".json_encode($output).";</script>";
}
```

So on cart page load i see *jsonCartData=************ script tag below cart_totals div,  but when Update Cart is clicked, my tag disappears entirely.

I need to know why this is the case, and what additional action I need to trigger to get the new output after the cart_totals div when Update Cart is done. Why would an update cart action not include retriggering the *woocommerce_after_cart_totals* hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each time something changes, an Ajax request is made and the corresponding sections on the page are updated.

If you want to hook into the Ajax calls, you should use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` filter.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments(array $array): array
{
    // Your logic …

    $array['#my-script-css-selector'] = <<<HTML
    <script id=my-script-css-selector>
        console.log('hello')
    </script>
    HTML;
    return $array;
};

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 10, 1);
```

Note, that there is a Stack Exchange *extra* for WordPress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this does not work. even just trying console.log('test')  doesnt work using this filter on Update Cart button

Comment: @DavidWilliams My mistake, we have to return the whole array, not only the added entry. I updated the answer. Also, the element hast to be included on the page, so WooCommerce can find it by the specified selector, and it can be updated.

Comment: got it. it works now. thanks